# Allocation of $\mathbb R^2$

Tags: differential-equations

Let $z_1,\ldots,z_n$ be $n\ge 1$ distinct points of $\mathbb R^2$. Define the potential function $U: \mathbb R^2 \to\mathbb R$ by

$$U(x):=\sum_{1\le i\le n} \log(|x-z_i|),$$

where $|\cdot|$ denotes the Euclidean norm. Denote by $F$ be the negative gradient of $U$, i.e.

$$F(x):=-\nabla U(x)=-\sum_{1\le i\le n} \frac{x-z_i}{|x-z_i|^2}.$$

For any $x\in\mathbb R^2$ that is different from $z_1,\ldots,z_n$, define the integral curve $Y\equiv Y_x$ by $Y(0)=x$ and

$$\frac{dY(t)}{dt}=F(Y(t)),\quad \forall t\ge 0.$$

By standard results about flows on vector fields, the curve $Y$ can be defined over some maximal domain $[0,\tau\equiv \tau_x)$ with $0<\tau\le \infty$. Can we prove for almost every $x\in\mathbb R^2$

$$\lim_{t\uparrow\tau} Y(t) \mbox{ exists and belongs to } \{z_1,\ldots,z_n\}?$$

If so, the space $\mathbb R^2$ is divided into a partition $V_1,\ldots, V_n$ defined by

$$V_i:=\big\{x\in \mathbb R^2: \lim_{t\uparrow\tau_x} Y_x(t)=z_i\big\}.$$

PS: The case $n=1$ can be easily handled. Set $z_1\equiv z$ and it holds that

$$\frac{d|Y(t)-z|^2}{dt}=2(Y(t)-z)\cdot \frac{dY(t)}{dt}=-2(Y(t)-z)\cdot\frac{Y(t)-z}{|Y(t)-z|^2}=-2.$$

This implies $|Y(t)-z|^2=|x-z|^2-2t$ for all $t<\tau$. In particular, $\tau<\infty$ and $t\mapsto |Y(t)-z|^2$ is decreasing. If $\lim_{t\uparrow\tau} |Y(t)-z|^2\neq 0$, we see immediately the solution can still be extended at $t=\tau$, which contradicts the maximally of $\tau$. Hence $\lim_{t\uparrow\tau} Y(t)=z$.

Comment: @ChristianRemling Absolutely right. Thanks for pointing out the typo

Comment: It's false for $n\ge 2$ because there are equilibrium points (for example, if $n=2$, then $F((z_1+z_2)/2)=0$).

Comment: @ChristianRemling Thanks for the answer. If my understanding is correct, $Y(t)$ will only converge to the equilibrium points $y$, i.e. $F(y)=0$. Is this right? Does this convergence hold for all initial points $x$ (probably different to $z_i$)?

Comment: @ChristianRemling I've made some edits to clarify that I pursue the convergence for almost every $x\in\mathbb R^2$. Do you think this may make my claim true?

Comment: Yes, if $F(x)=0$, then the solution with this initial value $x$ is $Y_x(t)=x$, so doesn't converge to one of the $z_j$.

Comment: If $F(x)\not= 0$, it could still be that $Y_x\to z_j$, but there are dangers such as attracting equilibrium points (maybe not likely) or periodic orbits.

Comment: @ChristianRemling Thanks again Christian. Do you have promising arguments to eliminate these two scenarios? Or do you have an example where there exists a non-neglieable set of points $x$ such that $Y_x(t)$ does not converges to $z_i$

Comment: I think this is mainly a matter of plotting some typical $F$'s. A tool to *establish* existence of periodic orbits is Poincare-Bendixson, though that's of course the opposite of what you want here.

Comment: @ChristianRemling I think you definitively provide a way for counter-examples, while the difficulty here is how to choose such $n$ and $z_1,\ldots, z_n$....

Comment: @ChristianRemling Inspired by your comments, it seems that $n=2$ is a counter-example. I'm just not sure for this case whether $\tau_{x^*}=\infty$ or not, where $x^*=:(z_1+z_2)/2$

Answer (score 0):

Following the hints of Christian Remling, my claim is not true. Take $n=2$ for example. A straightforward computation implies that the only equilibrium point $x^*$, i.e. $F(x^*)=0$, is given as

$$x^*=\frac{z_1+z_2}{2}.$$

Denote by $J_F(x^*)$ the Jacobian matrix of the vector field $F$ at the point $x^*$. Again by computation one obtains

$$-Tr\big(J_F(x^*)\big)=\frac{8}{|z_1-z_2|^2}=det\big(J_F(x^*)\big).$$

Namely, the two eigenvalues of $J_F(x^*)$ have strictly negative real part and thus the equilibrium $x^*$ is asymptotically stable, i.e. there exists $\delta>0$ such that for any $x\in\mathbb R^2$ s.t. $|x-x^*|<\delta$, $Y_x(t)\to x^*\notin \{z_1,z_2\}$.

Comment: The log function is strictly concave. So, for $n=2$, how can any point on the straight line segment connecting $z_1$  and $z_2$ be a stable equilibrium point?

Comment: @IosifPinelis I'm applying Hartman–Grobman theorem (see e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stability_theory). I don' understand why the strict concavity plays a role here. Do you mind giving more details?

Comment: The strict concavity of the log implies for $n=2$ that the potential function $U$ is strictly concave on the straight line segment (say $S$) connecting $z_1$ and $z_2$. So, from any relatively interior point of $S$, you can move a bit towards $z_1$ or $z_2$ so that $U$ is strictly decreasing during such a movement.

Comment: @IosifPinelis Why $U$ is strictly decreasing when moving on $S$? Indeed $U(x^*)=\max_{z\in S}U(z)$. How do you have the monotonicity along $S$?

Comment: No, I did not say that we have monotonicity along $S$, and we do not have it. However, at each point $x\in S$, we have a strict decrease of $U$ either on the segment from $x$ to $z_1$ **or** on the segment from $x$ to $z_2$.

Comment: @IosifPinelis Thanks Iosif. I get what you mean. As $t\mapsto U(Y(t))$ is decreasing, then any point $x\neq x^*$ on $S$ should move along $Y_x(t)$ to either $z_1$ or$z_2$. I will think why my reasoning is wrong. Feel free to give an answer

Comment: I think your conjecture is true, even with the following additions: (i) the exceptional set (say $X$) of points $x$ is the finite union of algebraic curves; (ii) all points $x\in X$ are unstable; (iii) the movement starting at any $x\in X$ is either periodic or stationary and hence $\tau_x=\infty$ for $x\in X$; (iv) $\tau_x<\infty$ for $x\notin X$; (v) $\tau_x$ is continuous in $x\in\mathbb R^2$; in particular, $\tau_x\to\infty$ as $x$ goes to a point in $X$. However, I have no proof for any of these statements.

Comment: Previous comment continued: I guess one can try to use a dynamical systems approach to prove that the exceptional set $X$ is of measure $0$.

Comment: @IosifPinelis Many thx Iosif. Indeed, I just don't know how to check that the equilibrium points $x\in X$, i.e. $F(x)=0$, are unstable. For a generic $n$, it's hard to obtain the explicit expression of $x$, and so it's not trivial to compute the Jacobian matrix